# Data Modeling: one-to-many relationship without unique identifier

Tags: sql, database, t-sql, database-design, data-modeling

Consider the following partial data model of open medical cases and their corresponding insurance:

```
**Cases**
CaseId (PK)  
PatientId (FK)  
CaseNote  
...

**CaseInsuranceProfiles**  
CaseId (PK)(FK) 
InsuranceId (PK)(FK)
InsuranceType {Primary, Secondary, Tertiary} (PK)(FK)
EffectiveDate

**Insurances**  
InsuranceId (PK)
InsuranceName
InsuranceAddress  
InsuranceCity  
...
```

Unfortunately, this model presents a problem.  It does not allow for the case to have duplicate records for an instance of each insurance and insurance type.  For instance, if the case in question has two primary insurance policies from Insurance A (as allowed in some states).  I've refined the model to the following in an effort to normalize the data and provide a unique identifier for the CaseInsuranceProfiles table that is not a compound key:

```
**Cases**
CaseId (PK)  
PatientId (FK)  
CaseNote  
...

**CaseInsuranceProfiles**  
InsuranceProfileId (PK)  
CaseId (FK) 
InsuranceId (FK)
InsuranceType {Primary, Secondary, Tertiary}
EffectiveDate

**Insurances**  
InsuranceId (PK)
InsuranceName
InsuranceAddress  
InsuranceCity  
...
```

However, this model presents a new model, namely that my surrogate key (InsuranceProfileId) still doesn't uniquely identify each record.  Could anyone make a recommend a change to the data model that would allow me to uniquely identify each record correctly?
Note: I realize that I could create a table similar to:

```
**CaseInsuranceProfiles**  
InsuranceProfileId (PK)  
CaseId (FK) 
InsuranceId (FK)
PrimaryInsurance  
SecondaryInsurance  
TertiaryInsurance
EffectiveDate
```

However, this does not allow me to account for multiple primary, secondary, or tertiary insurances.  Also, my goal is to identify the insurance profile of each case, in other words, I'd like to be able to use one key to display all of the insurances for a particular case.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have two primary insurance policies from Insurance A, how do you tell them apart? Policy number? Color of paper?

Comment: The policy number would be easiest to use.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about:

```
 **CaseInsuranceProfiles**   
InsuranceProfileId (PK)   
CaseId (FK0)(AK)
InsuranceId (FK1)(AK)   
InsurancePolicyId (FK1)(AK) 
CaseEffectiveDate 

**InsurancePolicies**
InsuranceId (PK)(FK) 
InsurancePolicyId (PK)
InsuranceType {Primary, Secondary, Tertiary}
```

Answer (score 0):

From a business point of view, I would want to know the priority of each insurance, I.e. Which policy pays first.   I would add a priority field and make that part of your key.